# Why won't the hyperref package work?

Tags: hyperref

I have a document where I want to create links from my table of contents, citations and references, in an ordinary way.  My first line is

```
\documentclass[draft,12pt,oneside]{CUNY_PhD}
```

and CUNY_PhD is a custom .cls file provided by my school.
When I insert

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

into the preamble, there is no error message, but it has no effect on the document.  If I do this in a test document, it works fine.  Do I need to learn how to further customize the .cls?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured this out actually while posting the question, but figured I'd post it, plus this answer, anyway, since I couldn't find the answer by searching.

All I had to do was take out "draft" from the documentclass options!

Comment: you can also force `hyperref` while keeping `draft` for the rest of the document by passing the option `final` to `hyperref` alone: `\usepackage[final]{hyperref}`

Comment: That is an even better solution, since I want to alter this template as little as possible in achieving my linkage.

Comment: I didn't have the draft option in the document class still it is not working for me. Also, when I use the [final] option with \usepackage{hyperref} I get the following error: ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

Comment: I also have tried both recommendations. Still broke